# BizTalk - The app is neither deleting nor letting me to deploy

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment

Something went wrong with my BizTalk applications; I am unable to delete them and at the same time unable to deploy the latest from Visual Studio. I am working with BizTalk 2009.

The error being displayed on Visual Studio:

> A referenced BizTalk project is being in use by other process and thus is unable to update it

My host instance and the application are in stopped state. I tried deleting the dll s from GAC, but no use.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked that you don't have any suspended instances associated with any of the orchestrations, ports and schemas the app had?